# Two closest points on boundary of Postgis geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I have a table `geofences` which stores `geometry` of polygon.

I also have a point `A` which is inside the geometry. What I have to do is find the two closest points from point `A` that lie on the surface of the polygon geometry.

Function in PostGIS:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION accuracyCheck(Polygon geometry
                                        ,decimal lat
                                        ,decimal lon)
  RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$BODY$

DECLARE height DECIMAL;
DECLARE accuracy VARCHAR(250);

BEGIN 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE closePointStorage AS
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(geometry
                                ,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lat lon)',0)
                                )
                ) AS closestPoint
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geometry) as geometry
   FROM gfe_geofences
   WHERE is_active=true
   ) As tempName;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE areaStorage ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((23.0808622876029 96.1304006624291
                                        ,28.0808622876029 99.1304006624291
                                        ,100              200
                                        ,23.0808622876029 96.1304006624291
                                        ))'
                              ,0)
              ) AS area;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE distanceStorage ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT ST_Distance(
          ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.0808622876029 96.1304006624291)',-1)
         ,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.0808622876029 99.1304006624291)',-1)
         ) AS distance;

height = (SELECT area FROM areaStorage)
        /(0.5*(SELECT distance FROM distanceStorage));

IF height < (SELECT radius_meters
             FROM gfe_geofences Where is_active=true) THEN
   accuracy = "FullConfirm";
   RETURN accuracy;
ELSE
   accuracy = "PartiallyConfirm";
   RETURN accuracy;
END IF;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I just want to find two points on boundary of polygon geometry. Just like I have found one from the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE closePointStorage AS
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(geometry
                                ,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lat lon)',0)
                                )
                ) AS closestPoint 
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geometry) as geometry
   FROM gfe_geofences
   WHERE is_active=true
   ) 
AS tempName;
```

Other then this point I have to find one more with distance greater then the point find above but smaller then the rest of points.

Comment: double lat1 = Math.toRadians(26.5534d);
  double lon1 = Math.toRadians(75.4925d);
  double lat2 = Math.toRadians(28.3650d);
  double lon2 = Math.toRadians(77.1232d);
  double dellat = (lat2 - lat1);
  double dellon = (lon2 - lon1);
  double R = 6371;
  double a = Math.sin((dellat) / 2) * Math.sin((dellat) / 2)
    + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin((dellon) / 2)
    * Math.sin((dellon) / 2);
  double c = 2 * (Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)));
  double d = R * c;
  System.out.println("Value of distance in km = " + d);

Comment: calculated the distance in loop for each point from geometry with point A and find up the two least or minimum distance from that all.

Comment: If you only care about the points in the geometry, and not the line segments between points, you could convert the boundary of the polygon into a MULTIPOINT, find the closest point, remove it and then find the second closest point.

Comment: It is very hard to decipher the comment you added. Update your question with proper format for such a purpose. Also add some explanation to the big function in your question: what is it supposed to do? Where does it fail exactly? What should the result look like (example values)?

Comment: If you care about points on the line segments, the second closest point isn't well defined. Imagine you have the line y=1, and the point x=2,y=2. The closest point on the line is x=2, y=1. The second closest point would be "right next to" x=2, y=1, but for any point you choose (say x=2.01,y=1) there is another closer one (x=2.005,y=1).

Comment: I guess the main question is " what are you trying to achieve , why do you need those two points"

Comment: what if the polygon is a symmetric triangle or squaare and point A is in the middle, so you have 3 or 4 points which are equidistant?

Comment: -1 Question is unclear and author ignores requests to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Use ST_DumpPoints() to dump the points of the polygon, then select from that order by ST_Distance to A  limit 2. ?

So it is something like

```
SELECT * from ST_DumpPoints(poly) order by ST_Distance(A,geom) asc limit 2;
```

(assumes that this is an inner select where poly is the polygon, A is the point  to compare to and geom is the geom column of one of the points in the poly being compared)

Comment: this will naturally not pick points on a line, only the points in the polygon definition. Also it would be faster if you could just order them by the square of the distance.

Answer (score 1):

There generally is no second closest point on the boundary polygon, if you include the lines. Just like there is no real number second closest to zero.
Either you only wish to consider the points at the corners, like Markus suggests.
Or you have only one closest point.

Answer (score 1):

1) Kind of a left-field idea, but to find the *second*-closest point to your destination, why not find the closest point to the point you already found?

2) Or, more germaine to your specific question,

- find the set of points within some reasonable range of the point,
- find the intersection of that set with the set of points lying on the polygon border (which I am guessing may be another PostGIS function; haven't used postG in a while so I'm not sure)

3) Farther into left field, dump some of your dataset into Mongo and use the $near function... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to find the edge of the polygon that passes the closest to the point in question

[image: distance from line problem]

To obtain the distance 'd' of point 'C' from line [A,B]
First translate all points so A is at 0,0

```
B -= A  //vector subtraction
C -= A
```

Then normalize B so it is of length 1.0

```
len = sqrt( B . B) //dotproduct of two vectors is the length squared
B /= len  //scalar divide by length
```

Find length from A that is at right angles to C

```
dotp = B . C  //dot product again
closestPointOnLine =  B * dotp  //scalar multiply
```

Now get the distance

```
diff = (C - ClosestPointOnLine)
d = sqrt(diff . diff)
```

Not sure how to do that in SQL. You will need to do the above for each edge on your polygon, and then find the smallest value 'd'

By the way the sign of the cross-product of B and C will now tell you whether the point is on the inside of the polygon or not

Comment: Your algo is good and understandable , good efforts by you , I would try to use the same in Sql because my dependency is to have this kind of algorithm to be implemented in sql only.